# Error installing Broom and Nlme package in R

Tags: r, broom

I am currently using RStudio for R right now. I am trying to use the broom::tidy function but am unable to install the broom package.

```
install.packages("broom")
```

generates the error:

> ERROR: dependency ‘nlme’ is not available for package ‘psych’
>   * removing ‘/home/gherr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/psych’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘psych’ had non-zero exit status
>   ERROR: dependencies ‘psych’, ‘nlme’ are not available for package ‘broom’
>   * removing ‘/home/gherr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/broom’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
>   The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/tmp/RtmpwPtSkh/downloaded_packages’

```
install.packages("nlme")
```

generates this error:

> Installing package into ‘/home/gherr/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘nlme’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)

It appears that I am only unable to install the 'nlme' package and the other two installs are failing because it is a dependency.

Comment: Your R version is fairly old. Are you able to update it?

Comment: You can try: install.packages("broom", dependencies = TRUE).

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct; you can't install nlme, because your R version is too old to support it. You need to upgrade [to R >= 3.4.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/).

Comment: Or install an older version of `nlme` from its [archive directory](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/nlme/).  Or, if you're on Ubuntu or Debian, install the prebuilt r-cran-nlme.  It could still be that broom wants a different version...

Comment: I just installed version 3.4.4 but am unable to switch RStudio to use it instead of the 3.2.3. I installed broom successfully once I was in the new version so I just need to switch my RStudio Preferences.